# Gradle error Cannot cast object 'lib' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection'

Tags: gradle, task

I'm getting a error that states

> Cannot cast object 'lib' with class 'java.lang.String' to class
>   'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection'" on the classpath line.

I define a task in gradle:

```
task convert(type:JavaExec){
    classpath = 'libs/com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse_3.8.3.5/lib'
    main = 'com.sun.javacard.converter.Main'
}
```

Can you tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the problem:

```
classpath = 'libs/com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse_3.8.3.5/lib'
```

According to https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:classpath classpath should be a FileCollection, not a String.

http://www.jonathanpearlin.com/2014/08/12/gradle_javaexec_classpath.html has some useful information about setting classpath yourself - it looks like you probably want to set it to `files(['libs/com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse_3.8.3.5/lib'])` or something like that.